# Is there an unlimited data plan for living in Italy?

Tags: italy, data-plans

I am planning on temporarily relocating to Italy for a few months and I was wondering if there was an unlimited data plan. I have found some for foreigners but they tend to only last a few days and are quite pricey. As I will be staying there for quite a while, I would like to know if there are any "resident" plans that would be cheaper, last longer and provide unlimited data.

Comment: I think it's on topic, the same can be used by a non-resident who wants to stay in Italy for say three months or so.

Comment: How much is "quite pricey" and what would you consider to be "cheaper"?

Comment: @NeanDerThal Not necessarily, there could be some that require residency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Italy there are only few operators that provides a good and reliable coverage everywhere. 
None of them has an unlimited Gb offer for mobile internet. 
There are some plan with 30 Gb per month or even more with subscription. 
But if you stay only some months it would be difficult to subscribe for a long-term engagement.

Anyway, I am not so sure that you can easily require a sim card without having your actual residence in Italy. Once you live here and you get a certificate and all related documents so you can easily go to a shop and buy a sim card in a couple of minutes.

Comment: If I did live there, would I be able to find unlimited (just so I can be educated about all of the plans)

Comment: no. As I said, the few good operators don't offer unlimited data plan.

Comment: Ah OK, what's the highest one could get at a reasonable price point

Comment: I don't know how much is "reasonable" for you, neither how many Gb per month are reasonable for you. You can check on the website of the operators, which are Tim, Vodafone, Tre (or wind, they are the same one)